Problem with logs in Jenkins pipeline when using Publish Over SSH and SSH Pipeline Steps plugins
I have a Jenkins Pipeline that uses the Publish Over SSH and SSH Pipeline Steps plugins to execute a shell script on a Java build server.
The whole process works correctly, except when the Maven line is executed and many log lines are generated.
When it reaches this point, the Jenkins Pipeline does not end, only after reaching the timeout period.
If I reduce the number of Maven log lines to 30, the Jenkins Pipeline runs correctly, otherwise it does not.
Pipeline:
        ...
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {                    
                    def remote = [
                        name: 'vm-dev',
                        host: 'dev.myhost.com',
                        user: 'user',
                        identityFile: '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/ssh-key',
                        allowAnyHosts: true
                    ]                    
                    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "/home/user/workspace/dev/scripts/java15/02-build.sh ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                }
            }
        }
        ...

The shell script:
#!/bin/bash

set -e

source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk use java 15.0.2-open

mvn clean install -U -DskipTests=true -q #The log problem is here

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Fail."
    exit 1
fi
echo "Success."

exit 0

Thanks for helping.
If I reduce the size of the shell script output log, the Pipeline works correctly.
I have already tested the advanced execution options of Publish Over SSH, without success.


You can try increasing the log buffer size in Jenkins to handle more log lines. This can be done by configuring the log-buffer plugin or adjusting Jenkins' log settings.
You can use tee command to write logs to both the console and a file
mvn clean install -U -DskipTests=true -q | tee build.log then use archiveArtifacts in the Jenkins pipeline to save the build.log file.

